# UnicodeEncodeError during NumPy structured array creation

Tags: python, numpy

I need to store some `followthemoney.proxy.EntityProxy` objects (in a other words, `EntityProxy` is a legal entity object, e. g. a company) and its id with NumPy structured array. So I define following `dtype` (company id looks like `0000012345`):

```
company_dtype = [('cid', 'S10'), ('company', 'object')]
```

`EntityProxy` object has `name` attribute (Unicode string of an arbitrary size). While this attribute contains only Basic Latin letters, array created successfully. But if company name contains Latin Extended A Unicode symbols (e. g. the name is `"Letter Ł"`), it throws the `UnicodeEncodeError` exception:

```python
test1 = np.array(['0000098765', company1], dtype=company_dtype)
```

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0141' in position 7:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

The `__repr__` method of `EntityProxy` object returns a string, which is combination of hexadecimal string (not the `'cid'` from `dtype` above) and name:

```python
# <E('4922bf8e06bf2cbc6a65d3a36b6dd8211a995a33','Letter Ł')>
def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return "<E(%r,%r)>" % (self.id, str(self))
```

I tried to change structured array `dtype` to:

```
 company_dtype = [('cid', 'S10'), ('company', 'U')]
```

but had the same error.

But when I try to create an ordinary (non-structured) NumPy array *with the same object*, **it works!**

```python
# in an array, company2 is 
# [<E('4922bf8e06bf2cbc6a65d3a36b6dd8211a995a33','Letter Ł')>]
test3 = np.array([company2])
```

Full code (variable values in comments taken from PyCharm IDE debug):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np
from followthemoney import model

schema = model.get("Company")

# creation of the followthemoney.proxy EntityProxy objects
# company with  Latin Extended A Unicode symbol in its name
company1 = model.make_entity(schema)
company1.make_id(['id 1'])
company1.add("name", "Letter Ł")
# Basic Latin
company2 = model.make_entity(schema)
company2.make_id(['id 2'])
company2.add("name", "Letter A")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    company_dtype = [('cid', 'S10'), ('company', 'O')]
    try:
        test1 = np.array(['0000098765', company1], dtype=company_dtype)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        # UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0141' in
        # position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
        pass
    # test 2 is
    # [(b'0000012345', '0000012345'), (b'Letter A', <E('6352b36388511435d0395100145bde280663cfe2','Letter A')>)]
    test2 = np.array(['0000012345', company2], dtype=company_dtype)
    # for test3 and test4, its dtype is `object`
    test3 = np.array([company1])  # [<E('4922bf8e06bf2cbc6a65d3a36b6dd8211a995a33','Letter Ł')>]
    test4 = np.array([company2])  # [<E('6352b36388511435d0395100145bde280663cfe2','Letter A')>]
```

##### Questions:

1. Why creation of the structured NumPy array with `dtype="object"` fails, but creation of the ordinary NumPy array is successful *for the same object*?
2. Which is correct `dtype` for the structured NumPy array in this case?

Comment: what is `test3.dtype`?

Comment: @hpaulj `object` too.

Comment: 'S10' is a byte string dtype that can only hold ASCII.  Use ' U20' for unicode strings.  Use `dtype=object` if you want to store things that aren't strings or numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 company_dtype = [('cid', 'U10'), ('company', object)]
```

Now 'cid' can store a unicode string, while the 'company' field will still be the company object.

The `UnicodeEncodeError` error came from the 'S10' dtype.

Comment: Thank you, I just found error in my code. In fact I pass to structured array two items, e. g. `'0000012345', company2`, because I would store it as one item, but dtype I had declared is `[('cid', 'S10'), ('company', 'O')]`. Correct `dtype` for my case is a nested: `[('entity', [('cid', 'S10'), ('company', 'O')])]`, and with it array have correct structure `[((b'0000098765', <E('4922bf8e06bf2cbc6a65d3a36b6dd8211a995a33','Letter Ł')>),)]`